# Java EE Weblogic migrate to WildFly 15

Tags: java, rest, jersey, wildfly

I'm trying to migrate a Java EE 7 application from a WebLogic server (it works well on it) to WildFly. But Rest requests work as it is not clear. Maybe someone came across? I show the configuration code and dependencies. I would be grateful for any help.
Basically errors about Content-type pop up:
MessageBodyReader not found for media type = text / html; charset = UTF-8;

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
 <deployment>
      <exclude-subsystems>
          <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
         <subsystem name="resteasy" />
          <subsystem name="webservices" />
      </exclude-subsystems>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
```

Rest

```
@GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, AbstractFacade.TYPE_JSON_UTF})
    public List<Country> findAll() {
        return countryBeanLocal.findAll();
    }
```

Request

```
countries = restClient.readEntity(
                    restClient.getWebTargetByPath("country")
                            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, RestClient.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .get(), new GenericType<List<Country>>() {
                    });
```

The most interesting thing is that after rebooting the server it works once and the second one does not.

Comment: Sounds like you're getting some exception on the server side and the server is sending you the error html page. Thats why the error message shows text/html. You should get the response as a `Response` and check the status, and if it is not a success status code, check the body. I'm bet it is the error html page. If so, figure out what the error on the server side is.

Comment: @Paul Samsotha Thanks for the answer, I’m trying to fix it on the server side =) Interestingly, there are no such problems on the WebLogic server and the code has not changed.

Comment: Do you need to use Jersey?  In general I've found porting between app servers is easier if you're just using, in this case, standard JAX-RS.  Pulling in an alternate JAX-RS implementation - under the covers Wildfly uses RestEasy - can create conflict.  By using standards, you don't care.  Indeed, WLS should not require the Jersey dependencies too.

Comment: @stdunbar Yes, I need to use a jersey, but I can’t get to not use RestEasy. Thanks for the answer . Maybe you can still tell something. Since I may not understand what you are saying =)